# Await state async

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

For speed we sometimes return response to consumer before state is saved in DB. Sometimes (Mostly for our automated consumers) this can break because the want to make actions on the saved data before it is saved. I wrote this little helper

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetWithRetry<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string errorOnTimeout) where TEntity : class
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    do
    {
        var entity = await _context.DbSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        if(entity == null)
            await Task.Delay(100);
        else
            return entity;
    } while(stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));

    throw new Exception(errorOnTimeout);
}
```

Used like

```
var existingBooking = await GetWithRetry<Booking>(b => b.BookingKey == confirmCommand.BookingKey, "Booking key not found");
```

Any pitfalls? `Task.Delay` should scale well since it returns the thread to the pool, and if the data exists in DB the first time around it should not give much more overhead than an extra wrapped task?

Comment: In order to avoid answers addressing multiple different versions of the code, I rolled back your edit. If you want the final version reviewed, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: A bit unnecessary, but I don't mind. Its the task parts I want ideas around. Those haven't changed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems good to me with a few remarks

> ```
> public async Task<TEntity> GetWithRetry<TEntity> (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string errorOnTimeout) where TEntity : class
> {
>     var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
>     stopwatch.Start();
>
>     do
>     {
>         var entity = await _context.DbSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
>         if(entity == null)
>             await Task.Delay(100);
>         else
>             return entity;
>     } while(stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
>
>     throw new Exception(errorOnTimeout);
> }
> ```

- You should use braces `{}` for single statement `if` and `else` to make your code less error prone.
- Do you really think that it could take more than 16 minutes until the state is saved ? Maybe `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds()` with a value of `2000`  would be the better choice.
- hardcoding the timeout value isn't that good. You should make it more flexible by passing in an argument with a default value.
- by reverting the condition the `else` would become redundant.
- By convention, you should append "Async" to the names of methods that have an Async or async modifier.

Applying the mentioned changes would lead to

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetWithRetryAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string errorOnTimeout, double timeoutMilliseconds = 2000D) where TEntity : class
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    do
    {
        var entity = await _context.DbSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            return entity;
        }

        await Task.Delay(100);

    } while (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds));

    throw new Exception(errorOnTimeout);
}
```

You should also use a more specific exception type.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, thats a bug :D It should be milliseconds. The code is just a draft for the time being. The question is more about the Task parts.

Comment: For exit early statements i like if (entity != null) return entity; on one line